# My xamarin.ios app gets crashed on iphone but running fine on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, xamarin.ios

I am developing an ios app using xamarin.ios studio.

I have finished it and it runs fine on simulator and iphone4 too. Later now i am face app crashing on iphone but running well on simulator. I could not able to find. Please help me.

Here is some of error logs:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x395671f0 __pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x395d1792 pthread_kill + 54
libsystem_c.dylib               0x39517fd8 abort + 72
365Invoicing                    0x0064525e 0xec000 + 5608030
365Invoicing                    0x00649e06 0xec000 + 562739
libsystem_platform.dylib        0x395cbf90 _sigtramp + 40
libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x395d1792 pthread_kill + 54
libsystem_c.dylib               0x39517fd8 abort + 72
365Invoicing                    0x006de4b8 0xec000 + 6235320
365Invoicing                    0x006456a4 0xec000 + 5609124
365Invoicing                    0x006502ba 0xec000 + 5653178
365Invoicing                    0x00644052 0xec000 + 5603410
365Invoicing                    0x0063e5b2 0xec000 + 5580210
365Invoicing                    0x0031e71c 0xec000 + 2303772
365Invoicing                    0x00107c44 0xec000 + 113732
365Invoicing                    0x0015ab7c 0xec000 + 453500
365Invoicing                    0x006dd464 0xec000 + 6231140
365Invoicing                    0x006deb98 0xec000 + 6237080
CoreFoundation                  0x2e7f4284 __handleUncaughtException + 576
libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38fa4f50 _objc_terminate() + 172
libc++abi.dylib                 0x3885d1c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
libc++abi.dylib                 0x3885cd28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38fa4e12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
CoreFoundation                  0x2e727f30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
CoreFoundation                  0x2e727c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
UIKit                           0x31078ecc -[UIApplication _run] + 756
UIKit                           0x31074148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
365Invoicing                    0x0015a7d0 0xec000 + 452560
365Invoicing                    0x00124708 0xec000 + 231176
365Invoicing                    0x001246c8 0xec000 + 231112
365Invoicing                    0x000f103c 0xec000 + 20540
365Invoicing                    0x002e5b64 0xec000 + 207139
365Invoicing                    0x0064fc5c 0xec000 + 5651548
365Invoicing                    0x0068c0c6 0xec000 + 5898438
365Invoicing                    0x0068f36a 0xec000 + 5911402
365Invoicing                    0x0068f1a8 0xec000 + 5910952
365Invoicing                    0x0063e3d4 0xec000 + 5579732
365Invoicing                    0x006dbfa0 0xec000 + 6225824
365Invoicing                    0x0062251c 0xec000 + 5465372
libdyld.dylib                   0x394b1ab4 start + 0
```

Theard 0 only has crashed. Other threads are running good.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: do i use thread and security functions on Main.cs file?

Comment: Care to symbolicate results? Why don't you debug the app on the device and see where it crashes? Then put some try/catches around it. Also, you should check into Xamarin.Insights or Raygun.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the console output for the application, since this crashed due to an unhandled Objective-C exception

Comment: de icaza , ok sir,  i will look Objective C. i have one more doubt to ask you. how can i save username and password in Keychain? i store it using your sample codes on gIthub. its too running fine on iOS simulator. but while trying with real divice, app gets crashed. what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to handle your exceptions using,

```
@try 
{
//your code goes here.
}
@catch
{
//your catch block
}
@finally 
{
//your finally block
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: vignesh, what is need for try catch at main.cs in xamarin project? there i did nothing, bro.